# Paypal Mass Payment not working.. Using MASS PAYMENT API

Tags: paypal

I am using Mass Payment of paypal in one of my modules. I provided all the parameters as asked. But evertime I m getting a response

```
 MassPay failed: Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012%2d02%2d24T08%3a53%3a08Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 49f2824e8cf17
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 51%2e0
    [BUILD] => 2571254
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security%20error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

What can be done to resolve this issue as I already given much time to solve the issue.But 1 thing i  noticed that error code is 10002 & error short msg is "security error" whose error code is 10008. So it that a prob??

Answer (score 0):

> 10008 Security error Security header is not valid

Typically, this error is a result of one of the following:

1. Wrong API credentials are being used.
2. Right API credentials are sent to the wrong environment
   *i.e. - Live API credentials sent to Sandbox environment, or vice versa*

Verify you are using the correct API credentials for the right environment. If the error persists, try re-generating your API credentials from within your PayPal account.